# How to optimise a linear function where training data only has pairwise relative ranking of data points

Tags: modeling, prediction, ranking

I have a data set containing a number of features and want to build a linear prediction model from this. However, I do not have a target score in the training set, instead I only have a number of pairwise rankings used to constrain the intended behaviour of the function.

The relative rankings provided are noisy (based on subjective measures of "which of these is better"), so there may not be a solution that assigns weights in such a way that the score matches all provided pairwise comparisons, but I'd like to find weights that give the lowest error in doing so.

Are there any known/standard approaches that would allow me to directly optimise this function, or ways of transforming a problem into a more traditional classification/regression problem when all I have is pairwise comparisons between data points?

Comment: You need to give some more details, this is very little to go on ...

Comment: @Kjetil What additional information are you looking for?  This question looks clear enough to me, but possibly I lack the imagination or experience to conceive of possible ambiguities.

Comment: I would like some data example, some context. But maybe it is me lacking imagination ...

Comment: @Kjetil Here's what the question says to me. The dataset consists of tuples $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are $d$-vectors (aka "features") and $z_i$ is a binary indicator of whether $x_i$ is considered "better" than $y_i.$ The model posits a $d$-vector $\beta$ of "weights" and random errors $\delta_i,\epsilon_i$ so that $z_i$ indicates whether $x_i\beta+\delta_i \ge y_i\beta+\epsilon_i.$ The question asks for procedures to estimate $\beta.$ I put aside technical issues of identifiability, assumptions about the errors, and so on, that any good answer would address.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use a function f(x) with a set of parameter to represent the "true" value. For example, your data is like (x1, x2, y1), (x2, x3, y2), (x1, x3, y3), etc. You can define your loss as:

```
loss += (f(x_i) - f(x_j)) - y_i
```

Then use the loss to update the parameter of f(x) to reduce loss.

Not sure whether the approach is mathematically correct. The result looks converging though.